How to update multiple origin OLEs embedeed in Power Point?(python,originpro)
I really need your help. I would greatly appreciate any advice you can give.
I am trying to sequentially open  multiple Originpro OLE objects embedded in a PowerPoint slide and automatically update the worksheets originally inside each object, but I am facing an issue.
When multiple OLE objects are open, op.find_sheet(origin function) only calls the first opened OLE object, so I cannot update the next one. so I tried  using op.exit or doverb(0) to close the   first OLE object and then reconnect  theapplication with op.attach(origin function) to update the next OLE object, but I am unable to establish the reconnection to the origin application.
The approximate code is as follows:
import os
import win32com.client
import originpro as op

powerpoint =             win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
powerpoint.Visible = True

origin = win32com.client.Dispatch("Origin.ApplicationSI")

origin.Visible = True

 for slide_index, slide in enumerate(presentation.Slides)

 for shape_index, shape in   enumerate(slide.Shapes):

ole_name = shape.Name

if "origin" in ole_name.lower():

shape.OLEFormat.DoVerb(1)

wks = op.find_sheet('w', 0)
wks.from_df(data)
shape.OLEFormat.DoVerb(0)
op.detatch()
op.utils.exit()
op.attach()

I can successfully iterate through and open OLE objects, but after closing the completed OLE object, an error occurs when trying to reconnect with Origin.
additionally, I tried using time.sleep and gc.collect, but it didn’t work well.”
